# how to deal with asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript

I have two asynchronous objects fn1 and fn2 and sometimes I want to run them synchronously.

For simplicity I wrote the code in this way:

```
var fn1 = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fn1");
    },200);
};

var fn2 = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fn2");
    },100);
};

fn1();
fn2();
```

but let's suppose is not possible to modify the fn1 and fn2 object.

What is the best way to run fn2 only when fn1 has finished to be executed?

Comment: *"run fn1 only when fn2 has finished"* I assume you have that reversed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute `f1()` when `f2()` has finished, use the method as described and shown below.

Create a poller function, which checks for variable/property changes created by method `fn2`. Example:

```
function fn1(){/*...*/}
function fn2(){
    //Lots of code, including:
    window.someDynamicVar = "SPECIAL_token"; //Unique, only defined by this func
}
(function(){//Anonymous wrapper, don't leak variables
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        //check whether an unique environment change has been made by fn2():
        if(window.someDynamicvar == "SPECIAL_token"){
            clearInterval(timer); //Clear the poller
            fn1(); //Call fn1
        }
    }, 200); //Poller interval 200ms
})();
```

The concept behind this code is that the `fn2()` function changes variables during/after execution, which can be read. When such a change has been detected, the poller is cleared, and `fn1()` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

> *"...let's suppose is not possible to modify the fn1 and fn2 object."*

Without modification, they will behave as asynchronous functions are meant to behave; they will run asynchronously.

If you have foreknowledge of the duration in the first function, you could delay the execution of the second by the same duration.

```
f1();
setTimeout(f2,200);
```

Comment: I assumed tgat the author did not want fn1 to execute straight away.

Comment: Async functions, such as XHR will not be handled properly using this method.

Comment: @RobW: You mean because you can't have foreknowledge of the duration, right?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ Yes. The only way to get the OP's result is by using a poller function (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839633/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-function#7839704).

Comment: @RobW: That's why I said *"If you have foreknowledge of the duration..."*. My answer is based on the requirements set forth in the question, one of which is that the functions must not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback function.

http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

```
var fn2 = function (myCallback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fn2");
        myCallback();
    },100); };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, there isn't a pretty way. Are you sure you can't change teh functions so they receive continuation functions to call when they are done?

```
function f1(continuation){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("f1");
        continuation(); //kind of like a return...
    }, 100);
}
function f2(continuation){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("f2");
        continuation();
    }, 100);
}

f1(function(){
    f2( function(){
        console.log("this runs after f2 ends");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

fn1 and fn2 are most *certainly* objects, contrary to what is said below (or above), but that's a different story. The easiest way to do what you want to, it to provide an optional callback parameter.

```
var fn1 = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fn1");
        if (callback) callback();
    },200);
};

var fn2 = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("fn2");
        if (callback) callback();
    },100);
};
```

So instead of:

```
fn1();
fn2();
```

You would do:

```
fn1(fn2);
```

or to be explicit about it:

```
fn1(function() {
    fn2();
});
```

Comment: You forgot _but let's suppose is not possible to modify the fn1 and fn2 object._ :)

Answer (score -3):

1. `fn1` and `fn2` are not objects
2. Read up about `setTimeout`. Get `fn1` to call `fn2` when it is done

Comment: As I wrote I just made a very simple example. But the gist does not change.

Comment: In Javascript, functions are objects.

Comment: No they are not jtfairbank. Objects have properties and methods (functions). See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @EdHeal: Yes, functions are objects in JavaScript, and as such, they can (and do) have properties and method. Try: `alert((function(a,b,c){}).call)` and `alert((function(a,b,c){}).length)`. Or this: `alert((function(a,b,c){}) instanceof Object)`.

Comment: @Ed Heal: w3schools is a very bad reference and often says a lot of stupid things. You should use better sources next time.